# For the Google Places API, how are supported types added such as a "golf course" type?

Tags: google-places-api

How are supported types added such as a golf course type?

Comment: can you provide more info in your question? so people can get where you getting stuck and you will get help as soon as possible

Answer (score 2):

1. Explore the list of [Supported Place Types](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/supported_types) to determine if the supported type you need exists. In this case ("golf_course"), there is not an existing type that may be used.
2. Explore the [Places API Issue List](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype%3aPlacesAPI%20type%3aEnhancement&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars) to learn whether there are any existing enhancement requests that will perform creation of the new Places Type.
3. In this case, there is. The existing [Issue 4197](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4197&q=golf&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars) requests a new "golf_course" supported type.
4. If you like, vote on the existing issue to raise its priority on the list of all Google Maps JavaScript API enhancments.